# Why occur Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined coffeescript in rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I using coffee script in Rails 5.2:
Refer at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

My code: welcome/index.html.erb:

```
<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#990000')">Paint it red</a>
<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#009900', '#FFFFFF')">Paint it green</a>
<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#000099', '#FFFFFF')">Paint it blue</a>
```

welcome.coffee:

```
@paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
  element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  if textColor?
    element.style.color = textColor

$ ->
  $("a[data-background-color]").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    backgroundColor = $(this).data("background-color")
    textColor = $(this).data("text-color")
    paintIt(this, backgroundColor, textColor)
```

But it not working and occur error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[image]

My Gemfile had add:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Why occur  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined coffeescript in rails 5.2?

Comment: Can you check if your `application.js` requires the jquery lib? see more here https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails#installation

Comment: Do you use turbolinks?

Comment: @MaxForasteiro: application.js had add. i update question.

Comment: @ Vasilisa:yes, i create rails app, default exist gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was resoled by change order lib:`jquery` go to above `turbolinks`

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

to

```
//= require rails-ujs   
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .  
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Comment: And you can remove `rails-ujs` since you use `jquery_ujs`

Comment: For me, I need to add the `//= require jquery3` on top of `//= require turbolinks
`. Rails 5.2.4.4